# Cannot sync database for Django app on its Heroku postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to migrate my postgres database to Heroku for a django application. In my settings.py file, I have the following, as dictated by the Heroku tutorial:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}
```

However, when I run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb`I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If we're [reading the same tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings), it suggests using `DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()`. You've completely replaced the `DATABASES` dictionary; they've simply added a new key. That might not be the issue, but it's worth checking. Also, make sure you've `git commit`ted and `git push`ed your latest code to Heroku.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your help. Turns out, however, that I had another file in my settings directory that was messing things up. Commenting that out made everything work!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the that the problem was that I had another file called local.py in my settings folder for my project. Tree as follows:

```
├── microblog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── base.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── local.py
│   │   └── local.pyc
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── Procfile
└── requirements.txt
```

Since I was following the Getting Started wit Django Tutorial, I had the following in my local.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<pwd>',
        'NAME': '<name>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

That was causing the problem. I tried adding the file to my .gitignore, but that didn't work. The solution was to actually comment these lines out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Commenting `local_settings` content solved it.